# null pointer is returned

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a test that I defined like this:

```
ClassName FileHandle;
ClassName1* data; //I want function to define this later

FileHandle.getData(data); //this is null after the call but isn't in function it calls
                          //why isn't the pointer defined from the method called? How fix?
```

---

The function it calls looks like this:

```
void ClassName::getData(ClassName1* data)
{
    char * buf = "lots of data";        
    data = new ClassName1(buf, sizeof(buf)); //it's in there
}
```

I'm sure it's an issue with my understanding of pointers and references.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  Why isn't the value of data still defined when it returns to my test?

I saw examples of pointers and function calls [here](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~sjac/c-to-cpp-info/references) but I'm having trouble finding an example like this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397310/return-statement-returning-a-null-pointer-value-and-not-the-desired-value) seems like it might be similar too, but I'm still confused.

Comment: Do you understand why `void f(int i) { i = 3; } void g() { int j; f(j); }` doesn't set `j` to `3`? It's really the same thing here, and if you do understand that, it would help get better answers if you can explain the difference you see that makes you think your example does change `data`.

Comment: You're trying to change the pointer address but you're passing the pointer by value :P

Comment: @DGomez - It won't let me call getData(&data).  I tried changing the function to getData(ClassName1& data), along with it but it won't let me instantiate a new ClassName1 in getData.

Comment: `sizeof(buf)` might not be what you expect, by the way.

Comment: @alain - do you know a better way to see if buf has data in it?

Comment: Yes, `strlen(buf)` returns the length of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the pointer itself by reference `&`:

```
void ClassName::getData(ClassName1* &data2)
```

For clarity I renamed the variables to `data1` and `data2` so you can see that they are different. Only when passing by reference are they effectively the same, otherwise the address stored in the local pointer `data2` is destroyed after the `getData` function exits and the NULL address originally stored in the input `data1` remains unaltered.

The call syntax remains the same:

```
FileHandle.getData(data1);
```